# Is there an api to add/remove users in Office 365?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

My company uses Office 365 for email, calendar and all that.  I'd like to be able to manage users from our internal application.  And by manage, I mean add or remove from groups.  Or create new groups and add people to those.  Or make people admins...

Is there an API for that?  Either .NET or Web?

I've tried the Microsoft Graph reference application (e.g. https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/), but it can't even log me in - always gives `Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. We received a bad request error.  AADSTS90093: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do everything you want to do, you have to use the Microsoft Graph API: http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/overview/overview 
The Graph Explorer you're trying to use (e.g. https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/) is the website used to test GET calls.

The error you get is because you're not logged in with a user who have the rights to call this API, try with an admin user or give the rights to your user with an admin account.

Comment: More specifically, the user you're using to log in to the Graph Explorer does not have permissions to consent to the permissions needed by the app. (Rémi's solution is correct--sign in to Graph Explorer with a user that is an admin of the directory.)

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret The thing is that if I log in to Office 365, and click People, I can easy add/remove people to/from groups, make them admins, etc...  I can also create/delete groups.  I might not be a domain admin, but I do have permissions.

Comment: I don't think you can create new users from "People" (which is a view in Exchange Online)--you can only create contacts, or Office 365 Groups. You don't need to be a directory admin for any of these operations. (Careful, the term "domain admin" might be confused with an on-premises AD domain admin.) https://portal.office.com/#ActiveUsersPage is where you would create a new user--can you get there?

Comment: right on @PhilippeSignoret, you are correct. To create users you need to be an administrator. To create personal contacts or groups from the UI you don't need to be an administrator. 
From the API you will need Group.ReadWrite.All permission scope, right now it requires and admin to consent. 
To add a member to a group: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/members/$ref, body: {"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid>"}